# Why I cannot append a value to a structs' slice using a reference?

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I Go, I assumed slices were passed by reference, but this seems to work for values
but not for the array itself. For example, If I have this struct:

```
    l := Line{
        Points: []Point{
            Point{3, 4},
        },
    }
```

I can define a variable, which gets passed a reference to the struct's slice

```
slice := l.Points
```

And then if I modify it, the original struct referenced by the variable
is going to reflect those modifications.

```
slice[0].X = 1000
fmt.Printf(
    "This value %d is the same as this %d", 
    slice[0].X, 
    l.Points[0].X,
)
```

This differs from the behavior of arrays which, I assume, are passed by value.
So, for example, if I had defined the previous code using an array:

```
l := Line{
    Points: [1]Point{
        Point{3, 4},
    },
}
arr := l.Points
arr[0].X = 1000
fmt.Println(arr.[0].X != s.Points[0].X) // equals true, original struct is untouched
```

Then, the `l` struct wouldn't have been modified.

Now, if I want to modify the slice itself I obviously cannot do this:

```
slice = append(slice, Point{99, 100})
```

Since that would only redefine the slice variable, losing the original reference. 
I know I can simply do this:

```
l.Points = append(l.Points, Point{99, 100})
```

But, in some cases, it is more convenient to have another variable instead of having
to type the whole thing.

I tried this:

```
*slice = append(*slice, Point{99, 100})
```

But it doesn't work as I am trying to dereference something that apparently is not a pointer.

I finally tried this:

```
slice := &l.Points

*slice = append(l.Points, Point{99, 100})
```

And it works, but I am not sure what is happening. Why is the value of slice not overwritten? How does `append` works here?

Answer (score 6):

Let's dispense first with a terminology issue.  The [Go language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec) does not use the word *reference* the way you are using it.  Go does however have pointers, and pointers are a form of reference.  In addition, slices and maps are kind of special as there's some underlying data—the array underneath a slice, or the storage for a map—that may or may not already exist or be created by declaring or defining a variable whose type is `slice of T` or `map[T1]T2` for some type *T* or type-pair *T1* and *T2*.<sup>1</sup>

We can take your usage of the word *reference* to mean *explicit pointer* when talking about, e.g.:

```
func f1(p *int) {
    // code ...
}
```

and the implied pointer when talking about:

```
func f2(m map[T1]T2) { ... }
func f3(s []T) { ... }
```

In `f1`, `p` really is a pointer: it thus refers to some actual `int`, or is `nil`.  In `f2`, `m` refers to some underlying map, or is `nil`.  In `f3`, `s` refers to some underlying array, or is `nil`.

But if you write:

> ```
> l := Line{
>     Points: []Point{
>         Point{3, 4},
>     },
> }
> ```

then you must have written:

```
type Line struct {
    // ... maybe some fields here ...
    Points []Point
    // ... maybe more fields here ...
}
```

This `Line` is a struct type.  It is not a slice type; it is not a map type.  It *contains* a slice type but it is not itself one.

You now talk about passing these slices.  If you pass `l`, you're passing the entire `struct` by value.  It's pretty important to distinguish between that, and passing the value of `l.Points`.  The function that receives one of these arguments must declare it with the right type.

For the most part, then, talking about *references* is just a red herring—a distraction from what's really going on.  What we need to know is: *What variables are you assigning what values, using what source code?*

With all of that out of the way, let's talk about your actual code samples:

> ```
> l.Points = append(l.Points, Point{99, 100})
> ```

This does just what it says:

- Pass `l.Points` to `append`, which is a built-in as it is somewhat magically type-flexible (vs the rest of Go, where types are pretty rigid).  It takes any value of type `[]T` (slice of *T*, for any valid type *T*) plus one or more values of type *`T`*, and produces a new value of the same type, `[]T`.
- Assigns the result to `l.Points`.

When `append` does its work, it may:

- receive `nil` (of the given type): in this case, it *creates* the underlying array, or
- receive a non-nil slice: in this case, it writes into the underlying array or discards that array in favor of a new larger-capacity array as needed.<sup>2</sup>

So in all cases, the underlying array may have, in effect, just been created or replaced.  It's therefore important that any *other* use of the *same* underlying array be updated appropriately.  Assigning the result back to `l.Points` updates the—presumably one-and-only—slice variable that refers to the underlying array.

We can, however, break these assumptions:

```
s2 := l.Points
```

Now `l.Points` and `s2` both refer to the (single) underlying array.  Operations that modify that underlying array will, at least potentially, affect both `s2` *and* `l.Points`.

Your second example is itself OK:

> ```
> *slice = append(*slice, Point{99, 100})
> ```

but you haven't shown *how* `slice` itself was declared and/or assigned-to.

Your third example is fine as well:

> ```
> slice := &l.Points
> *slice = append(l.Points, Point{99, 100})
> ```

The first of these lines declares-and-initializes `slice` to point to `l.Points`.  The variable `slice` therefore has type `*[]Point`.  Its value—the value in `slice`, that is, rather than that in `*slice`—is the address of `l.Points`, which has type `[]Point`.

The value in `*slice` is the value in `l.Points`.  So you *could* write:

```
*slice = append(*slice, Point{99, 100})
```

here.  Since `*slice` is just another name for `l.Points`, you can also write:

```
l.Points = append(*slice, Point{99, 100})
```

You only *need* to use `*slice` if there's some reason that `l.Points` is not available,<sup>3</sup> but you *may* use `*slice` if that's more convenient.  Reading `*slice` reads `l.Points` and updating `*slice` updates `l.Points`.

---

<sup>1</sup>To see what I mean by *may or may not be created* here, consider:

```
var s []int
```

vs:

```
var s = []int{42}
```

The first leaves `s == nil` while the second creates an underlying array with the capacity to hold the one `int` value `42`, holding the one `int` value 42, so that `s != nil`.

<sup>2</sup>It's not clear to me whether there is a promise never to write on an existing slice-array whose capacity is greater than its current length, but not sufficient to hold the final result.  That is, can `append` first append 10 objects to the existing underlying array, then discover that it needs a bigger array and expand the underlying array?  The difference *is* observable if there are other slice values referring to the existing underlying array.

<sup>3</sup>Here, a classic example would occur if you have reason to pass `l.Points` or `&l.Points` to some existing (pre-written) function:

- If you need pass `l.Points`—the slice value—to some existing function, that existing function cannot change the *slice* value, but could change the *underlying array*.  That's probably a bad plan, so if it *does* do this, make sure that this is OK!  If it only *reads* the slice and underlying array, that's a lot safer.
- If you need to pass `&l.Points`—a value that points to the slice value—to some existing function, that existing function *can* change both the slice, and the underlying array.

If you're writing a new function, it's up to you to write it in whatever manner is most appropriate.  If you're only going to *read* the slice and underlying array, you can take a value of type `[]Point`.  If you intend to update the slice in place, you should take a value of type `*[]Point`—pointer to slice of `Point`.

Answer (score 2):

Append returns a new slice that *may* modify the original backing array of the initial slice. The original slice will still point to the original backing array, not the new one (which may or may not be in the same place in memory)

For example ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SSpFysC4uZL))

```
slice := []int{1,2,3}
fmt.Println(len(slice))
// Output: 3
newSlice := append(slice, 4)
fmt.Println(len(newSlice))
// Output: 4
fmt.Println(len(slice))
// Output: 3
```

While a slice can be described as a "fat pointer to an array", it is not a pointer and therefore you can't dereference it, which is why you get an error.

By creating a pointer to a slice, and using `append` as you did above, you are setting the slice the pointer points to to the "new" slice returned by `append`.

For more information, check out [Go Slice Usage And Internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt didn't work because slices are not pointers, they can be considered reference types. Append will modify the underlying array if it has enough capacity, otherwise it returns a new slice.

You can achieve what you want with a combination of your two attempts.

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/3MGvnwGs-3m)

```
l := Line{
    Points: []Point{
        Point{3, 4},
    },
}

slice := &l.Points

for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
    *slice = append(*slice, Point{99 + i, 100 + i})
}

fmt.Println(l.Points)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this might be sacrilegious, but, for me, it is useful to think of slices
as structs.

```
type Slice struct {
    len int
    cap int
    Array *[n]T // Pointer to array of type T
}
```

Since in languages like C, the `[]` operator is also a dereferencing operator, we can think that every time we are accessing a slice, we are actually dereferencing the underlying array and assigning some value to it. That is:

```
var s []int
s[0] = 1
```

Might be thought of as equivalent to (in pseudo-code):

```
var s Slice
*s.Array[0] = 1
```

That is why we can say that slices are "pointers". For that reason, it can modify its underlying array like this:

```
myArray := [3]int{1,1,1}
mySlice := myArray[0:1]
mySlice = append(mySlice, 2, 3) // myArray == mySlice
```

Modifying `mySlice` also modifies `myArray`, since the slice stores a pointer to the array and, on appending, we are dereferencing that pointer.

This behavior, nonetheless, is not always like this. If we exceed the capacity of the original array, a new array is created and the original array is left untouched.

```
myArray := [3]int{1,1,1}
mySlice := myArray[0:1]
mySlice = append(mySlice, 2, 3, 4, 5) // myArray != mySlice
```

The confusion arises when we try to treat the slice itself as an actual pointer. Since we can modify an underlying array by appending to it, we are led to believe that in this case:

```
sliceCopy := mySlice
sliceCopy = append(sliceCopy, 6)
```

both slices, `slice` and `sliceCopy` are the same, but they are not. We have to explicitly pass a reference to the memory address of the slice (using the `&` operator) in order to modify it. That is:

```
sliceAddress := &mySlice
*sliceAddress = append(mySlice, 6) // or append(*sliceAddress, 6)
```

### See also

- https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/slice-pass-as-value-or-pointer/2866/4
- https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals
- https://appliedgo.net/slices/